# ImagePicker doesn't give option to exit gallery

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My `ImagePicker` does not allow the user to go back/exit the gallery...(there should be a `cancel` button in the top right corner:

[image]

Here is my `ImagePicker`:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let key: String
    @Binding var uiImage: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
        var parent: ImagePicker
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let img = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.uiImage = img
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
}
```

And here is the View which uses it/triggers it to open:

```
struct EditableCircleImage: View {
    @ObservedObject var storage = Storages()
    let key: String
    let imgName: String?
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    @State var uiImage: UIImage?

    @Binding var showImagePicker: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        }
        .padding(8)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage){
            ImagePicker(key: self.key, uiImage: self.$uiImage)
        }
    }
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: There is a cancel button, it's in the top left. It's white.

Comment: Oh wow it is....accentColor(.white) must be causing that. Thankyou